# Slow firebase function response from background activity

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

The function shown below puzzles me for two reasons:

- the function execution terminates before all output is given
- the function execution takes more than 3 minutes; a very long time (so long, that it might not be because of the "cold starts" issue only).

When searching for bestpractices I found a hint, that background acitivities are slowed down after function execution is terminated (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#do_not_start_background_activities).

How can I create a function, that terminates after all output is created and avoids background activity?
Is there any way how to speed up the get() processing?

[screenshot of firebase functions dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnQQt.png)

[screensthot of firestore showing the document created to trigger the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RUuP.png)

Please have a look on the code:

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions .
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.evaluateScore = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.firestore   
  .document('organizations/{orgId}/persons/{personId}')  
  .onWrite(async (snap, context) => {

const newDocument = snap.after.exists ? snap.after.data() : null; 
const oldDocument = snap.before.exists ? snap.before.data() : null;    
console.log(`lastName: '${newDocument.personLastName}'; id: '${snap.after.id}'`);


// if only newDocument exists
if (newDocument != null && oldDocument == null ) {
  
  const arrayNameSplit = snap.after.ref.path.split('/'); 
  var orgId = arrayNameSplit[arrayNameSplit.length -3];    

  
  var listOfProfiles = newDocument.listOfProfiles;
  console.log(`listOfProfiles: `, JSON.stringify(listOfProfiles));
      
  for (let i = 0; i < listOfProfiles.length; i++) {
    db.collection('organizations').doc(orgId).collection('profiles').doc(listOfProfiles[i]).get()
    .then(docRef => {
      const profile = docRef.data();
      console.log(i, ' profileTitle:', JSON.stringify(profile.profileTitle))
    }).catch(e => {
      console.error('something went wrong', e)
    });
  }    
}
  });
```

Comment: `function execution terminates before all output is given`,    `.then(docRef =>`, looks like your using promises, the function is always going to terminate before the async operation is done.  You need to handle this from were your calling the function from.  For your slowdown, I would say it's because your executing everything at once, your likely hitting what's called thrashing, and that can have a very bad effect on performance.

Comment: Hi Keith, thank you for your response. I added a screenshot to show the test data, that I created to trigger the function (.onWrite). It only contains the reference to 2 other documents. Therefor I wonder if this can result in "thrashing" already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asynchronous calls in your code, but are not telling the Cloud Functions runtime about that (through the return value). It is very likely that your database `get()` calls don't even complete at this stage.

To fix that problem, you can use `await` inside the loop or `Promise.all`:

```
exports.evaluateScore = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.firestore   
  .document('organizations/{orgId}/persons/{personId}')  
  .onWrite(async (snap, context) => {

const newDocument = snap.after.exists ? snap.after.data() : null; 
const oldDocument = snap.before.exists ? snap.before.data() : null;    
console.log(`lastName: '${newDocument.personLastName}'; id: '${snap.after.id}'`);


// if only newDocument exists
if (newDocument != null && oldDocument == null ) {
  
  const arrayNameSplit = snap.after.ref.path.split('/'); 
  var orgId = arrayNameSplit[arrayNameSplit.length -3];    

  
  var listOfProfiles = newDocument.listOfProfiles;
  console.log(`listOfProfiles: `, JSON.stringify(listOfProfiles));
      
  for (let i = 0; i < listOfProfiles.length; i++) {
    const docRef = await db.collection('organizations').doc(orgId).collection('profiles').doc(listOfProfiles[i]).get();

    const profile = docRef.data();
    console.log(i, ' profileTitle:', JSON.stringify(profile.profileTitle))
  }    
}
});
```

There may be more problems with your code, so I recommend reading the documentation on [sync, async and promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for future questions.

Comment: Thank you! With your code the time for execution is reduced from 3 minutes to 5 seconds (in cold start). Also I studied all of Doug's 9 videos, that you linked with the documentation.